# Arithmetic calculations on two date-columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a big table (>30M rows) with info on a certain kind of transactions. There is one column with the full date of the transaction, and one column with the year of birth of the user.

The columns are:

`trans_date` of the type DATETIME (*ex: 2006-02-20 00:00:00*)

`birth` of the type YEAR (*ex: 1970*)

What I want is to be able to calculate the age of the person at the transaction, in a where clause. For example, 2006 - 1970 = 36. So a person born in 1970 was 36 years old at the year of the transaction.

This is what I want to do (pseudo-ish code):

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE (YEAR(trans_date) - birth) = '36'
```

So that I would get every record where the person was 36 years old at the year of the transaction. Is that possible?

Comment: Doesn't your query work as is?

Comment: Looks like it should work. Have you even tried running it?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work. I get "BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(year(`myDB`.`myTable`.`trans_date`) - `myDB`.`myTable`.`birth`)' "

Answer (score 2):

The error happens when the `birth > year(trans_date)` as you're dealing with an unsigned type and get a negative value.

You can get around this by forcing a signed result instead (assuming `birth` is the unsigned value):

```
WHERE (YEAR(trans_date) - CAST(birth AS SIGNED)) = 36
```

Also, don't use quotes for the literal number - the calculation returns a number and you should compare it with a number, not a string (that would be implicitly converted to a number).

The MySQL manual states that

> By default, subtraction between integer operands produces an UNSIGNED
>   result if any operand is UNSIGNED

This can be controlled by changing a setting: `SET sql_mode = 'NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION`

See [this part of the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_unsigned_subtraction) for more information.

Also note that the determination of the `years` won't be exact as you lack the needed precision to actually determine the age (as you're comparing a date with a year and the users actual birth date might be before or after the trans_date).

Comment: The weird thing here is that there is actually no instance of birth > year(trans_date). As to the exactness, it's good enough the get the age of the year (transactionyear - birth year)

Comment: @Christoffer That's odd. If all birth <= year(trans_date) then you shouldn't get the error. The problem wasn't fixed by adding the cast ?

Answer (score 1):

Using YEAR() here will be imprecise, because it won't correctly match partial years / account for the fact that someones birthday has or has not yet passed.

You could do a calculation on the full part of their birth date compared to the current date, however that will be inefficient as MySQL has to do a calculation for each row and thus cannot use an index.

Best method is to calculate the target 'birth' date and compare the column to that, so that you can make use of an index on the column also.

Example:

```
WHERE
 trans_date
 BETWEEN
   DATE_SUB(CUR_DATE(), INTERVAL 36 YEAR)
   AND
   DATE_SUB(CUR_DATE(), INTERVAL 37 YEAR)
```

Test the edge cases (i.e. transaction date 1 day before, on, or after the birthday) to ensure you are correctly matching the range and not off by one.

Comment: Problem is that I only have the year of birth, not the full date. The column with birth date is of type YEAR and contains only the year.

Comment: Sorry you are right, this answer is incorrect and not helpful.  I also missed the fact that trans_date is not the current date.

Comment: No it's helpful. Gives me a little bit more to experiment with,